# How can I combine elements of an array that have a common element?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to take an array of number pairs:

```
[[2, 3], [2, 15], [3, 15], [7, 8], [8, 7], [11, 15]]
```

and if two of these number pairs have a number in common, combine them and display the unique values, ultimately creating this array:

```
[[2, 3, 15, 11], [7, 8]]
```

Order of the numbers in the output array is not important.  What would be the best solution?

Comment: Is `[[2, 3, 15, 11], [7, 8]]` intended to be representative, or is it the the desired output for the array of pairs you have given?  If not, I suggest you replace the with the desired output; if so, further explanation is required.  I also suggest you reduce the size of the input array to the minimum needed to clarify the question.  (Edit the question, rather than adding comments.) As the first two pairs are `[2, 3]` and `[2, 15]`, should [2, 3, 15] be a member of the output array?  Is order important?  For  `[7, 8]` and `[8, 7]`, can the output array contain either `[7, 8]` or `[8, 7]`.

Comment: Edits made, I tried to address each of your clarification questions in the original question.  Appreciate the tips.

Comment: I think the best way to state your problem succinctly and unambiguously is in terms of connected subgraphs.  The array you start with is a list of the graph's edges, each (undirected) edge identified by a pair of nodes.  Your problem is to partition the edges into connected subgraphs, then convert each subgraph to an array of the subgraph's nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was corrected following Howard's comment.

```
[[2, 3], [2, 15], [3, 2], [3, 15], [7, 8], [8, 7], [11, 15], [15, 2], [15, 3], [15, 11]]
.each_with_object([]) do |e1, a|
  a.select{|e2| (e1 & e2).any?}.each{|e2| e1.concat(a.delete(e2))}
  e1.uniq!
  a.push(e1)
end
# => [[8, 7], [15, 11, 3, 2]]
```

Comment: Worked great, I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Does not work in all cases. E.g. just put `[11,15]` to the front, e.g. `[[11, 15], [2, 3], ...` and you'll get a wrong result.

Comment: This and others also have the downside of mangling the original array

Answer (score 1):

It's really just another mapping and sorting problem,:

```
array = [[2, 3], [2, 15], [3, 2], [3, 15], [7, 8], [8, 7], [11, 15], [15, 2], [15, 3], [15, 11]]
array.map{|a| array.each{|x| a |= x if (x & a).any?}; a.sort}.uniq
#=> [[2, 3, 11, 15], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: While it works and is simple, I think it is less efficient. You are creating the same array union potentially multiple times, and throwing away all but one. You also introduced `sort` just for the purpose of applying `uniq`.

Comment: Right. I'll take simpler over faster anytime though, especially when we're talking about nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as @sawa's solution - but works for all the cases:

```
def includes? item, groups
  groups.each{|sub|
    return true if sub.include?(item)
  }
  false
end

def add groups, match, item
  groups.each{|sub|
    if sub.include?(match)
      sub << item
      sub.uniq!
      return
    end
  }
end

def iterate arr  
  groups = []
  grp = []
      arr.each do |a,b|
        grp = [a,b] if grp.empty?
        if includes? a, groups
          add groups, a, b
        elsif includes? b, groups
          add groups, b, a
        else
          groups << [a,b]
        end
      end
  groups
end

arr = [[2, 3], [2, 15], [3, 2], [3, 15], [7, 8], [8, 7], [11, 15], [15, 2], [15, 3], [15, 11]]
p iterate(arr)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[[2, 3, 15, 11], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution:

```
def doit(a,b)
  return a unless b
  h = b.group_by {|e| (a[-1] & e).any?}
  h[true] ? a[-1] |= h[true].flatten : a << h[false].pop
  doit(a, h[false])
end

arr = [[2, 3], [2, 15], [3, 2], [3, 15], [16, 21], [7, 8], [8, 7], \
       [21, 44], [11, 15], [15, 2], [15, 3], [15, 11], [8, 9]]
doit([arr.pop], arr) # => [[8, 9, 7], [15, 11, 2, 3], [21, 44, 16]]
```